# Audio Technica ATR2100-USB Recording Issue

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, audacity, setup

I am facing a issue while connecting my ATR2100 to my desktop computer via USB. The sound volume that is being recorded is very low. I have to amplify it each time after recording which distorts the sound quality. I checked YouTube videos and there direct recording graph on Audacity much higher than me. Here are the details of my configuration:

```
Microphone: Audio-Technica ATR2100-USB 
Connection: USB 
Sound Card: Realtek High Definition Audio 
Computer: Intel Core i3 2100 
Motherboard: DH61WW
```

My queries are:

1. What could be causing this issue?
2. Will the extra Audio Interface resolve the issue?

Comment: There are many possible causes here - too many to list. On the upside, a standalone audio interface will almost certainly help; they reduce the noise floor, reduce latency, giver greater signal definition etc. I heartily recommend getting one.

Comment: Because it's a USB mic, I'm pretty sure it bypasses the Realtek soundcard. Are there driver settings, or settings in Window's `Recording Devices` dialog you can check? You used the term "direct recording graph", so I'm asuming you know very little about sound recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked other PCs as well. The issue was same. So I connected my Mic to Focusrite Scarlet 2i2 with XLR to 1/4" cable and its worked marvel. So decided to get a Audio Interface for PC. That's the only solution if you need a good quality sound input without distortion, clipping or audible background noises after amplifying it.

Comment: I have the same mic, and a scarlet 2i4 , and if I use XLR the level is still really low - I have to crank up the gain to almost max for it to work... Was that the same for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mic plugged into a front USB port on your computer it may be getting less power than expected. I have seen this more than once. Try connecting it to a USB port directly on the motherboard.